I want to download csv file the data needs to save different languages from database in c#
I want to download csv file the data needs to save different languages from database in c#
suppose i have japanese language data but the is not saving in csv file correctly it is displaying charaters instead of japanese language
i am using Visual strudio 2022 please help on this
below is my code
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
 [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
 ILogger log)


{
 List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>
 {
     new List<string> { "Name","Age","Language"},
     new List<string> { "Nagu","32", "頼もう" }
 };
 StringBuilder csvContent = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (var row in data)
 {
     string formate = string.Join(",", row);
     csvContent.AppendLine(formate);
 }
 UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();


 var preamble = utf8.GetPreamble();

 byte[] dt = utf8.GetBytes(csvContent.ToString());
 HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(csvBytes))
 {
     ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(dt);
     response.Content = content;
     response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
     response.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";

     response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
     { FileName = "output.csv" };
 }
 log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");



 return response;

}
output displaying like this


I'd really try to use a CsvHelper library instead of rolling my own, first. That alone might solve a bunch of problems you can run into when creating csv.

That output image looks like Excel (or something similar). Can you confirm it is at all capable of displaying japanese chars? Is it expecting a different encoding than UTF-8? - Which in itself is probably not the best choice from the unicode family if you regularly export japanese.

i want to display the data in csv file output i need data that is actual suppose if the input data is japanese i need japanese data but in image it is showing different data

Are you aware of how text encodings work? It's all "data". It might even be the correct "data". But if your displaying software does not decode the data to the correct glyphs, you get jibberish, as seen in the image.

Is there a reason for this line?: var preamble = utf8.GetPreamble();. You never use preamble.

in Language the output is é ¼ã‚‚ã†   i need japanese data instead of this which data i am sending as an input i need same data as output

i am using .NET 6.0

You keep saying that but it makes no sense. Please read the comments and research what is new to you. It is quite probably an encoding issue.
